# create Class diagram using JAVA code

Tags: java

Is there any softtware to create Class diagram, Activity diagram,Sequence diagram and any other related diagrams using JAVA Source code.

Comment: ArgoUML has an extension argouml-java: http://argouml-java.tigris.org/

Comment: most software that make such things not opensource

Answer (score 1):

Most UML tools can import source code and generate class diagrams.  Which tool are you using?

Sequence diagrams are more problematic, because you actually have to run the code.

IntelliJ enterprise edition, the best IDE in the world from JetBrains, can do both for you.

Answer (score 0):

You can generate UML diagrams as XMI (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XML_Metadata_Interchange) with Java and then process it with some tool that supports XMI.